# Inconsistent replication of count vectorizer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, countvectorizer

I am facing issues regarding inconsistency of the Countvectorizer of the ml feature package. When I reproduce the outcome of the countvectorizer and the vocabulary attached, I receive different results.

Root of the problem is that I receive different results of the LDA when I perform the same model (setting equal seed).

```
## Import packages
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer , IDF

#compute first model
countVectors = CountVectorizer(inputCol="requester_instruction_words_filtered_complete", outputCol="raw_features", vocabSize=5000, minDF=2.0)
model = countVectors.fit(tokenized_stopwords_sample_df)
result_tf = model.transform(tokenized_stopwords_sample_df)
vocabArray = model.vocabulary

#compute new model 
countVectors_new =  
CountVectorizer(inputCol="requester_instruction_words_filtered_complete", outputCol="raw_features", vocabSize=5000, minDF=2.0)
model_new_cv = countVectors.fit(tokenized_stopwords_sample_df)
result_tf_new = model_new_cv.transform(tokenized_stopwords_sample_df)
vocabArray_new = model_new_cv.vocabulary

##Check if both vocabularies are the same
set(vocabArray_new) == set(vocabArray)
# Result: false
```

According to this result I see that despite the same input column the count vectorizer of the ml package does not produce stable and replicable results.
Can yomeone help or provide an alternative for computing count vectorizer in pyspark?